# Llenas campo de una tabla con números php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-tabla

Hola, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para enumerar automáticamente mis datos llamados desde mi base de datos dentro de una tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí mi código:
https://pastebin.com/XxnE25Pw

Comment: Agrega aquí tu código por favor, por otro lado que versión de mysql usas?

Comment: version 2.10.3?

Comment: Seguro? Ya vamos en la versión 8 ejecuta esto SELECT VERSION;  Y Sandra la version

Comment: si, pero debería de funcionar igual sin importar la versión. creo.

Comment: A lo que voy, es que MySQL 8 trae integradas las *window functions* y una de ellas nos puede auxiliar para alcanzar el objetivo deseado, pero para esa posible solución sería importante saber que versión estás usando

Comment: claro si señor. Mira https://ibb.co/ZHSLKmW

Comment: En php sólo tienes que iniciar una variable contador e incrementarla en cada vuelta del bucle que recorre los resultados de la consulta. Añade el código en lugar de imágenes, te aconsejo que revises cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: pego mi código le añado los ` ` y me sale error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 2 opciones:

Si el número que quieres colocar quieres que sea **el mismo que identifica tu registro** en la base de datos, tendrás que crear una columna con nombre `"id"` y ponera como `AUTO_INCREMENT`, luego tan solo tendrás que usar `$mostrar["id"]`.

Si quieres **que la enumeración empiece por 1** y vaya incrementando sin importar qué registros tienes en la tabla, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$enumeracion = 1; // Al principio del código PHP, una sola vez

<td><?php echo enumeracion; enumeracion++; ?></td> // En cada registro de la tabla
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono con tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

tabla cabecera

```
<th scope="col">ID</th>
```

---

tabla body

```
<td><?php echo $mostrar['id']?></td>
```